# How to update 2nd column when enter value in st column wpf

Tags: wpf

have Two column First column have " Textbox" , and in 2nd column bind qty column by using DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Qty}".
Now what i need to do ,
if i enter 40 in column 1st then it will  automatically get update  in 2nd column.
means any update value in 1st column need to show in 2nd column.
withdout rebind Grid row.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var row = objPosItem.ParentOfType<GridViewRow>();
                    if (row != null)
                    {
                        row.Cells[6].Content = model.FinalPriceForShow.ToString();
                        row.Cells[6].HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
                    }
```